# How does Git determine a conflict when two branches are merged?

Tags: git

I am very confused about how Git determines conflicts between two branches. Take a look at the images below: Left vs. Right
On lines 36 vs. 36, 49 vs. 49, and 65 vs. 69, I expected Git to throw a conflict, but it did not. Now on line 110 vs. 114, it throws a conflict.
Please explain why that is. I am confused and need some explanations.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Conflicts do not deal with the *tips* of branches that you are merging.... it is depending on how changes are introduced in both branches involved *since their last common ancestor* (it's actually a little more complicated than that because there might be multiple merge bases for a single merge but it's a good enough generalization). So, I bet that you will see why there are or aren't conflicts if you consider how the file (or files) look at the merge base (which can be calculated by running `git merge-base branch1 branch2`).

I have this site where I *try* to explain the details: http://www.ezconflict.com/

Comment: Thank you, @eftshift0. I have downloaded the book; I will take a look. I really want to understand the concept. 